# How to rotate an image through code?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to rotate an image which is already flipped to 90 deg. So I am trying something of this sort:

```
this.image1.SetValue(PlaneProjection.RotationYProperty , 0.0);
```

It is giving me an exception of type `Exception`.

Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: Look at xaml. image has defined `PlaneProjection` attached property or maybe has some another transform?

Comment: got this idea from xaml only.
see it yourself.            

<DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="90" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.image1.SetValue(Image.ProjectionProperty, new PlaneProjection() { RotationY = 0 });
```